# Guice how to make a property dynamique?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-8, guice, guice-3

I have this interface classes:

```
public interface Query {
    String getQuery();
}
```

Query Builder implements Query

```
public class QueryBuilder implements Query {
    private String query;

    private final String table;

    @Inject
    public QueryBuilder(@Named("Table") String table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    
    public Query insert() {
        query = "INSERT ";
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Table is an abstract Class use as the generic class

```
public class Table {

    protected Query query;

    @Inject
    public Table(@Named("Table") Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

UserTable extends Table as would do some other tables.

```
public class UserTable extends Table {
    private Query query;

    @Inject
    public UserTable(@Named("UserTable") Query query) {
        super(query);
    }

    public String insert() {
        return query.insert().query();
    }
}
```

This is the QueryModule

```
public class QueryModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Query.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("UserTable")).to(QueryBuilder.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("UserTable")
    public String provideUserTable() {
        return "users";
    }
}
```

Here I test my code in a main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new QueryModule());
        Table table = injector.getInstance(UserTable.class);
        System.out.println("Insert statement: " + table.insert());
    }
```

I'm getting this nasty error

```
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for String annotated with @Named(value=Table) was bound.

Did you mean?
    * String annotated with @Named(value=Table1Query)
```

I want to make the table property dynamique for each Table using Guice Java. How can I do so ?

Comment: "Table is an abstract Class use as the generic class". This class neither abstract nor use generic types